# Given xor and the range of 2 numbers, find their maximum possible sum

Tags: python, algorithm, math, bit-manipulation, bitwise-xor

I got this task:

> You are given 5 integers a,b,c,d,k. Print the maximum value of x+y
> that follows the given conditions:
>
> - a<=x<=b
> - c<=y<=d
> - x^y=k    ('^' sign denotes XOR operation)
>
> Constraints:
>
> - 0 <= a <= b <= 10^18
> - 0 <= c <= d <= 10^18

**Explanation:**

- x and y are the 2 numbers,
- k is their xor value ,
- [a,b] is range of x ,
- [c,d] is range of y.

****My Attempt:****

```
found=False
a,b,c,d,k=map(int,input().split())
for x in range(b,a,-1):
    if found==True:
        break
    for y in range(d,c,-1):
        if x^y ==k:
            print(x+y)
            found=True
            break
```

I know its the brute force but this is the only algorithm I can think of to solve the problem but this is obviously not gonna work as the time complexity is O((b-a)*(d-c)) or in the worst case, it could take 10^36 operations. This approach needs to be optimized to logarithmic or constant time complexity.

Reading similar question from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-two-numbers-from-their-sum-and-xor-set-2/),

X+Y = (X ^ Y) + 2 * (X & Y)

So,

ans = k + 2*(X&Y)

So, I need to find the maximum value of and operation of 2 numbers whose range is given. But how to do it?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You're trying to perform a constrained optimization, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/optimize.html#

Comment: @ArrowRise How fast can that do it? (I'd be surprised if it were fast, but I'm not familiar with it at all.)

Comment: @ArrowRise I think this wont work as we need to find the maximum value of and operation of 2 numbers whose range and xor operation values are given. We cant traverse over their range. Also, its a maximization problem, not minimization.

Answer (score 0):

10^18 is about 2^60 (a little smaller). You can work on the bits and only check numbers that would give a valid xor result. This is already a lot better than your algorithm, but I don't know if it is good enough.

```java
public long solve(long a, long b, long c, long d, long k) {
    return solve(a, b, c, d, k, 0L, 0L, 1L << 59);
}

private long solve(long a, long b, long c, long d, long k, long x, long y, long mask) {
    if (mask == 0)
        return x >= a && x <= b && y >= c && y <= d ? x + y : -1L;
    if ((mask & k) == 0) {
        if ((mask | x) <= b && (mask | y) <= d) {
            long r = solve(a, b, c, d, k, x | mask, y | mask, mask >> 1);
            if (r > 0)
                return r;
        }
        if ((mask | x) > a && (mask | y) > c)
            return solve(a, b, c, d, k, x, y, mask >> 1);
    } else {
        if ((mask | x) > a && (mask | y) <= d) {
            long r = solve(a, b, c, d, k, x, y | mask, mask >> 1);
            if (r > 0)
                return r;
        }
        if ((mask | x) <= b && (mask | y) > c)
            return solve(a, b, c, d, k, x | mask, y, mask >> 1);
    }
    return -1L;
}
```

Comment: What language is that? I tried Java but it [doesn't work](https://tio.run/##lVNLc4JADL7zK3JyYIoM9HFoVfoH9OSx08MKW4u8nN2Vwlh@O80@imB1nO6BZJPNly9fhh2pyLTc02IXp123P2yyJIIoI5zDiiQFHC3LBLkgAk1VJjHkmLLXgiXF9u0dCNty52itGy5o7pUH4e0xI7LCLuiXgrEdj5dZRe3A9333Xn4e5OdReXgcZ2a1fausLLagC5RLXB3aGBsZGxubOsgT8KhbTngKCwiWMJ/D0/PslKkx7C9daJTVCd0GOyA44iJk6kKNb1wFZHixpCKC/p@YsbWxjXui@Ms5@QBbU0ZSjgrJw6g4sAIphwsgMJmgN1/ARnqNjEXaw1gMr5i8w8sLTAMzVo86AYNs2o2S3wNUE9CQw9e9fAxluywX1slyqeyvp@DCEAJnNkKSvRmEw1HPRmangnZEuZYLDbCWmNn1LRojGZQbez2nZqp6/VqgGacDFXoF@ieXaY1lHDO7qt8t4S4u7KoA2GZFxKeXk9pm7s2VDVv@VcRso5W/Qdt1Pw).

Comment: @KellyBundy yes it is Java, apparently | and & bind weaker than comparators. Should work now.

Comment: I noticed it doesn't matter in which number we set the bits as long we get valid x and y. Branching can be reduced. This could be O(logn) but I'm not entirely sure. I think if it will fail it will only do 1-2 steps before returning, but maybe not. If there is a solution it should be very fast.

Comment: https://tio.run/##xVRNb4MwDL3zK6wdKqLSamzapK0t@wPs1OO0QwpZRaFQhZSBOn47c0IoFKpqH5oWJGw9E/s9O2FDMzpJdize@GFV7farKPDAi2iawjMNYjgYhgZTQQWaLAl82GLIXAoexOuXV6B8nZKDsSxSwbbTZC@mO4yIKDZj9q7SmGSaJlHGTPv6dLnWzQC5HSL3AwQXOse3S8jMKA0DcGm@URKvoa6qXGrV0EpbT1tf25CgWNBLIVuahrAA24X5HO4eZqfRHEPIBApl2yBnYs9jXRmLYj0shVVCC3L83FJ5Sb2hocyDjAr2fc7a5toWVsu8Kyd4A7NWg1xl4MyschjDFT5jKEirpqMoB2cBFEYj9OYLWEmvkJhXe4j58AQyTwGPMLFdOZIuhZrDSLa6IdKt037yATk51migQkF@f9dxIBwHcb7ruFnmkLNqPJXTccDuaW14cHCQ4CDUaQc/3VhekuLUfesoccAbZv/a0enTLoFFKbvcyyGBH7by/3p45jjIJv7mNPyphLL/R1AXQl/6sqo@AQ

Answer (score 0):

Look at the numbers in base 2 as arrays of bits, largest to smallest.

There are 4 inequality constraints:

1. `a<=x` Satisfied at end, or if `x` first has a 1 where `a` has a 0.
2. `x<=b` Satisfied at end, or if `x` first has a 0 where `b` has a 1.
3. `c<=y` Satisfied at end, or if `y` first has a 1 where `c` has a 0.
4. `y<=d` Satisfied at end, or if `y` first has a 0 where `d` has a 0.

So after each bit we have a state consisting of which inequality constraints are currently done or active.  This state can be represented by a number in the range `0..15`.  For each state we only care about the largest sum of the values of the already set bits for `x` and `y`.

This is a perfect setup for dynamic programming.

```
def to_bits (n):
    answer = []
    while 0 < n:
        answer.append(n&1)
        n = n >> 1
    return answer

def solve (a, b, c, d, k):
    a_bits = to_bits(a)
    b_bits = to_bits(b)
    c_bits = to_bits(c)
    d_bits = to_bits(d)
    k_bits = to_bits(k)

    s = max(len(a_bits), len(b_bits), len(c_bits), len(d_bits), len(k_bits))
    while len(a_bits) < s:
        a_bits.append(0)
    while len(b_bits) < s:
        b_bits.append(0)
    while len(c_bits) < s:
        c_bits.append(0)
    while len(d_bits) < s:
        d_bits.append(0)
    while len(k_bits) < s:
        k_bits.append(0)

    a_open = 1
    b_open = 2
    c_open = 4
    d_open = 8
    best_by_state = {15: 0}
    for i in range(s-1, -1, -1):
        next_best_by_state = {}
        power = 2**i
        if 0 == k_bits[i]:
            choices = [(0, 0), (1, 1)]
        else:
            choices = [(0, 1), (1, 0)]
        for state, value in best_by_state.items():
            for choice in choices:
                next_state = state

                # Check all conditions, noting state changes.
                if (state & a_open):
                    if choice[0] < a_bits[i]:
                        continue
                    elif a_bits[i] < choice[0]:
                        next_state -= a_open

                if (state & b_open):
                    if b_bits[i] < choice[0]:
                        continue
                    elif choice[0] < b_bits[i]:
                        next_state -= b_open

                if (state & c_open):
                    if choice[1] < c_bits[i]:
                        continue
                    elif c_bits[i] < choice[1]:
                        next_state -= c_open

                if (state & d_open):
                    if d_bits[i] < choice[1]:
                        continue
                    elif choice[1] < d_bits[i]:
                        next_state -= d_open

                next_value = value + power * sum(choice)

                if next_best_by_state.get(next_state, -1) < next_value:
                    next_best_by_state[next_state] = next_value

        best_by_state = next_best_by_state

    possible = best_by_state.values()
    if 0 < len(possible):
        return max(possible)
    else:
        return None
```

print(solve(1000000000000000,2000000000000000,3000000000000000,3600000000000000,3333000333000333))

This program has performance linear in the number of bits.